# Numerical Integration involving multiple singularities

Tags: numerical-integration, singularity

I want to solve the following double integral numerically. This integral has singularities in two points.

```
 a = 10^-6;
 b = 10^-9;
 Δ =10^-3;
 h = 10^-1;
 δ = 10^-5;
 Ω = -h Sqrt[Δ^2 + δ^2];
 θ = 1/2 ArcTan[Δ/δ];
 t = 10000;

 NIntegrate[E^(-ω/(2a)) E^(-w/(2b))
((1 - Cos[(ω +w + Ω) t ])/(Sqrt[2] (ω + w + Ω)(ω + Ω)))
 Sqrt[w ω],{w, 0,1},{ω, 0, 1}, MaxRecursion -> 300, AccuracyGoal -> 10]
```

Note: singularities are $ω+w=-Ω$ and $ω=-Ω$. It can be solved in Mathematica and the answer is $1.7*10^{-12}$. But we know that the function has two singularities. Is this result authentic? How can I exclude the singularity points?

Thank you

Comment: Your code contains syntax errors when I copied it and pasted it to my notebook  ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/iPVKm.png) I know 2D math and subscripts notations is popular with the masses, but it makes for bad formatting when used outside the notebook and it causes more trouble than it is worth it.

Comment: what is the question here? the code runs just fine for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to [handle singularities with `NIntegrate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationStrategies.html#122144792). Concerning your question, Since you already know the location of singularities, simply remove them with `Exclusions` during integration.

```
NIntegrate[E^(-ω/(2 a)) E^(-w/(2b))((1 - Cos[(ω +w + Ω) t ])/(Sqrt[2] (ω + w + Ω)(ω + Ω)))
Sqrt[w ω],{w, 0,1},{ω, 0, 1}, MaxRecursion -> 300, AccuracyGoal -> 10,
Exclusions -> {ω + w + Ω==0, ω + Ω==0}]
```

> 1.75579*10^-12

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no, the result is insignificant (as is).  The error, according to `AccuracyGoal -> 10` is around `10^-10`, which is 100 times larger than the result.

To check `10^-12`, you should bump `AccuracyGoal` up above that, say to `12` plus half `MachinePrecision`, or `12 + 8`.

```
NIntegrate[
 E^(-ω/(2 a)) E^(-w/(2 b)) ((1 - Cos[(ω + w + Ω) t]) /
  (Sqrt[2] (ω + w + Ω) (ω + Ω))) Sqrt[w ω],
 {w, 0, 1}, {ω, 0, 1}, AccuracyGoal -> 12 + 8]
(*  0.  *)
```

To double check this answer, increase `WorkingPrecision` to see if the result is stable:

```
NIntegrate[
 E^(-ω/(2 a)) E^(-w/(2 b)) ((1 - Cos[(ω + w + Ω) t]) /
  (Sqrt[2] (ω + w + Ω) (ω + Ω))) Sqrt[w ω],
 {w, 0, 1}, {ω, 0, 1}, AccuracyGoal -> 12 + 8, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 20]
(*  2.9063486435043377577*10^-5449  *)
```

So you can have some confidence that the answer is approximately zero.